# Parental Controls on Windows Media Center

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center, parental-controls

I'm running a Windows Media Center box (using Windows 7 Professional). Movies are encoded as MKV files, each movie in its own folder, and I'm using YAMMM to provide metadata.

I have set up Parental Controls for both TV and DVD (DVD controls Movies as well, is this correct?) so that blocking is on, and blocks unrated movies, and has a maximum allowed rating of None (so it should block all rated AND unrated movies).

When I play a movie, it plays without asking for an access code, no matter what rating is set on the movie.

Has anyone else experienced this or knows what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the same issue, was told the user running windows media center couldn't be an administrator otherwise the parental controls would not work.

Comment: OK, that probably makes sense...